# object of abstract class type "Vector<LinkedList<int>>" is not allowed

Tags: c++, vector

```
template <class Type>
class AbstractVector : virtual public AbstractArrayClass<Type> {
public:
    virtual void insert(const Type& item, int index) = 0;
    virtual void remove(int index) = 0;
    virtual void add(const Type& item);
};

template <class Type>
class Vector : virtual public ArrayClass<Type>,
virtual public AbstractVector<Type>
{
protected:
    int _currSize;
    int _incFactor;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int n);
    Vector(int n, Type& val);
    Vector(const Vector<Type>& v);
    Vector(const ArrayClass<Type>& ac);
    virtual ~Vector();
    void operator= (const Vector<Type>& v);
    void operator= (const ArrayClass<Type>& ac);
    virtual void insert(Type& item, int index);
    virtual void remove(int index);
    virtual int size() const;
    virtual int capacity() const;
    virtual int incFactor(int f);
    void setIncFactor(int f);
    void setCapacity(int c);
};

template <class Type>
class LinkedList {
protected:
    Type* _info;
    LinkedList<Type>* _next;
public: 
    LinkedList<Type>();
    LinkedList<Type>(Type& val);
    LinkedList<Type>(int l, Type& val);
    LinkedList<Type>(LinkedList<Type>& list);
    void add(Type& val);
    void insert(Type& val, int k);
    void remove();
    void removeAt(int k);
    ~LinkedList();
    int size();
    Type& operator[] (int k);
    LinkedList<Type>& operator= (LinkedList<Type>& list);
};

template <class Type>
void Vector<Type>::insert(Type& item, int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index > _currSize)) {
        throw ArrayBoundsException();
    };

    // if new size is equal to maximum capacity increase it
    if (_currSize + 1 == _size) {
        setCapacity(_size + _incFactor);
    };

    // increment current size
    _currSize++;

    // copy all data
    for (int i = _currSize - 1; i > index; i--) {
        (*this)[i] = (*this)[i - 1];
    };

    // insert new item
    (*this)[index] = (Type)item;
}
```

The insert function from the AbstractVector class is fully defined, the code for the Vector class was provided by the textbook we're using in the course, but I've heard from everyone who's taken it that the provided code is terrible.

When I try to create the Vector,

```
Vector<LinkedList<int>> v;
```

It throws "object of acstract class type "Vector>" is not allowed: pure virtual function "AbstractVector::insert[with Type=LinkedList]" has no overrider" and C2259: "'Vector>': cannnot instantiate abstract class."

I've tried to look at other questions but the solutions seem to mostly indicate that the function isn't defined anywhere, which isn't the case.

Comment: Insert changed from `virtual void insert(const Type& item, int index)` to   `virtual void insert(Type& item, int index)` between `AbstractVector`  and `Vector`

Comment: use `override` to spot those kind of problem.

Comment: BTW: your copy constructor must be LinkedList<Type>( const LinkedList<Type>& list);

Comment: @engf-010 You can have a valid copy constructor without `const`, but obviously it would be suboptimal to write it that way in most cases.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the template parameters of the current instantiation inside the class definition. When declaring constructors, you can use just `LinkedList` and avoid writing `LinkedList<Type>`.

Comment: I hope you don't use any of this in production code.

Comment: @engf-010 Actually the compiler will not declare a `const T&` copy constructor in that case. The compiler only implicitly declares a copy constructor if you have *no* copy constructor defined yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the difference between your declaration of `insert` and that of `AbstractVector`'s:

Yours:

```
virtual void insert(Type& item, int index);
```

`AbstractVector`:

```
virtual void insert(const Type& item, int index) = 0;
```

Notice that yours is missing `const`